# How to yield the system of equation of this plane defined by two 4-dimensional vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

I'm stuck at a problem :
 Find the system of equations whose solution set is the plane :
[image]
I'm not sure how to fetch the system of equations and I guess c1 and c2 are free variables but I don't know how to use them. 
( Sorry for posting pic I didn't know how to write those matrices. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plane $\pi$ in four dimensions is completely determined by a point $Q$ (through which it passes) and a pair $\{u,v\}$ of linearly independent vectors (to which it is orthogonal). $\pi$ is then formed by the points $P$  that satisfy the system of equations:
\begin{equation}
  (P-Q)\cdot u=(P-Q)\cdot v=0.
\end{equation}
You may expand these equations in components, with $P=(x,y,z,w)$, and then you'll find a system of two equations over the variables $\{x,y,z,w\}$.

To be able to write the equations you should find the data $\{Q,u,v\}$. The easiest point $Q$ in $\pi$ to calculate is the one for $c_1=c_2=0$. Finding vectors orthogonal to $\pi$ is the same as finding the ones orthogonal to the vectors $\{w_1,w_2\}$ that multiply $c_1$ and $c_2$ in the definition of $\pi$.

A straightforward method for doing this last part is: take $u$ to have its third and fourth components to be zero, and then you can easily determine that the first two must be equal and of opposite sign. Then take $v$ to have the first two components to be equal and of the same sign (to make sure that it is linearly independent of $u$) and the third and fourth components will follow. The modulus of both vectors is, of course, arbitrary.

---

Therefore, the resulting final system of equations is:
\begin{equation}
x-y=x+y-6z+2w+10=0
\end{equation}

Comment: That was really helpful. It gave me an idea on how to convert parametric vector form to system of equations.

Comment: Can you be more specific about obtaining u and v? In 3-dimensional analysis I would have computed the cross product of 2 vectors but in 4-dimension I'm totally puzzled.

Comment: @BlackHole I'm glad it helped! The method I gave is just a fast, easy way of doing it for this specific case. If you want to do it in a more general way you could just solve the system of equations $w_1\cdot w=w_2 \cdot w=0$ ($w$ is the variable) and choose a basis $\{u,v\}$ of the solution space

Comment: I know this may sound silly but could you please include the final system of equations in your answer so that I could check my answer?

Comment: @BlackHole No problem, done. I might have made a mistake with the numbers, though